# DialogFragment missing content, only showing "ok" button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to display a dialogfragment from within a viewpager fragment. For some reason. The only thing that is showing up is the positive ok Button. Can someone help me out here?

Inside of my fragment. I'm calling.

```
DialogFragment cardDetails = CardDetails_Fragment.newInstance(cardItem);
cardDetails.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "card_details");
```

Here's my onCreateDialog method.

```
 @Override
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext = getActivity(); 
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_details, null);
    TextView cardAttempts = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_attempts);
    cardAttempts.setText(Integer.toString(_card.attempts));

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

          }
        });
    builder.setCancelable(false); 
     return builder.create();
}
```

This is what I get.

[image: Dialog Fragment displayed incorrectly]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply forgot to call [`setView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29):

```
builder.setView(view);
```